# Android Studio: Gradle failed to resolve dependencies

Tags: android, gradle, proxy, android-gradle-plugin

Getting error:

> Gradleconnectioncheck:app:unspecified Could not resolve
>   com.github.pstovk:MaterialDesignLibrary:1.3.
>
> > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/github/pstovk/MaterialDesignLibrary/1.3/MaterialDesignLibrary-1.3.pom'.
> >     jcenter.bintray.com

1. I've used proxy setting in Android Studio.
   And also tried this solution ([Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13828787/gradle-cant-resolve-dependencies-through-my-http-proxy)) which sets proxy in gradle, but It didn't work.

settings:

```
systemProp.https.proxyHost=http-proxy.nwie.net
systemProp.https.proxyPort=8080
systemProp.https.proxyUser=http-proxy.nwie.net/%USERNAME%
systemProp.https.proxyPassword=%PASSWORD%`
```

2. There is already `jcenter()` in build.gradle, which was suggested in [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29824809/gradle-fails-to-resolve-dependency-in-android-studio)

code:

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
```

Comment: did you try both http and https settings for proxyHost, proxyUser, and proxyPassword? Make sure that your username and password have proper escape characters if you have special characters in it.

Comment: I tried using systemProp.proxySet=true and http & https both and It's working! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried using systemProp.proxySet=true and http & https both and It's working!

```
systemProp.proxySet=true
systemProp.http.proxyHost=http-proxy.nwie.net
systemProp.http.proxyPort=8080
systemProp.http.proxyUser=http-proxy.nwie.net/%USERNAME%
systemProp.http.proxyPassword=%PASSWORD%`

systemProp.https.proxyHost=http-proxy.nwie.net
systemProp.https.proxyPort=8080
systemProp.https.proxyUser=http-proxy.nwie.net/%USERNAME%
systemProp.https.proxyPassword=%PASSWORD%`
```

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this issue by adding code :

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to include both http and https settings for proxyHost, proxyUser, and proxyPassword.

If that doesn't work, see this similar issue: https://github.com/navasmdc/MaterialDesignLibrary/issues/288

Try gradle sync and/or clean and build again like so:

`Tools -> Android -> Sync Project with Gradle Files`

If that fails, try running 'Rebuild project':

`Build -> Rebuild Project`

Also try switching over to navasmdc's repo of Material Design:
https://github.com/navasmdc/MaterialDesignLibrary